# How come the components keep going to the upper left corner?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm following a tutorial on how to build a simple app on android studio.
In the video he is able to drag his components or buttons wherever on the screen, whether its in the middle, or bottom right, etc. When I try however, it automatically goes to the upper left. How come and how do I fix that? I was able to manually change the attributes for some so that they were where their supposed to be, but I want to have it so i can just drag and drop wherever I wish. Please keep in mind that the code I post is the same that the user in the video uses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Just noticed, but I didn't mean to include the bottom half of the code because that was taken out when the button was deleted.
The following is what I and him actually have before placing new components.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Are you talking about the UI editor of android studio? If yes, then don't use it. It's buggy and unreliable. Just edit the xml by hand. Also, your `TextView` has some `constraint` attributes that are applicable when it's a child of `ConstraintLayout`. Maybe that's the problem? See if the tutorial uses `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Use `ConstraintLayout` instead.

Comment: The tutorial uses relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Replace `TextView`'s `app:layout_constraint...` attributes to `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also [there are](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) a lot of attributes that can be applied to `RelativeLayout`'s children.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I edited the question where I showed the actual code I was starting with. The new code doesn't have anything from <TextView and down. Is there a setting that automatically does it because in the tutorial the user just drags and drops wherever he pleases on the screen, compared to me where I need to manually change the XML file. Thank for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RelativeLayout` as your parent layout and in the `TextView` you're specifying constraints which work only with `ConstraintLayout`

Change your parent layout to `ConstraintLayout` and your constraints will work as expected.